# Does pressing ctrl-c several times make the running program close more quickly?

Tags: process, kill, signals

I often start to read a huge file and then want to quit after a while, but there is a lag from pressing 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to the program stops. Is there a chance of shortening the lag by pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key several times? Or am I wasting my keypresses?

Comment: I have noticed when running a process that calls various child processes, Ctrl-C will sometimes interrupt the running child, but not the parent process.  That is true in `bash`, but not the case in `zsh` which always closes the parent.  It is one of the reasons I like `zsh`.

Comment: Yes, just like pressing the elevator button or the cross-walk button repeatedly will cause the elevator to come sooner or the light to turn green quicker.

Comment: Yes just like elevator and crosswalk buttons, CTRL-C can also get sticky or rusty or develop iffy connections. Pressing more times is a good tactic because only one press has to register for the elevator to come, the walk sign to light up, or the program to close.

Comment: It was never wasted effort to smack your old (cathode ray tube) TV in case it didn't work, it was good to let off some steam. I view hammering Ctrl+C in much the same light (same goes for Esc). ;-)

Comment: @hippietrail but your shell will print out `^C` when it registers the press (at least bash does)

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't consider it wasting my keypresses -- I consider it venting some frustration in a non-damaging way. (I usually hit it 2-3 times, but that's partially because I "grew up on" terminals attached over phone lines where you couldn't always count on every single keystroke reaching the machine.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After the first <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, the program will receive [`SIGINT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGINT) and usually starts cleaning up (deleting tmp files, closing sockets, etc.). If you hit <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> again while that is going on, it *may* happen that you interrupt the clean up routine (i.e. the additional signal *might* be acted upon instead of being left alone), leaving a mess behind. While this usually is not the case, more commonly the additional signals are in fact sent *after* the process finished (because of the inherent delays in the interaction of the operator with the system). That means that signals are received by another process (often shell, but not always). If that recipient doesn't handle this signal properly (like shell usually does - see Jenny D's answer) you may be unpleasantly surprised by the outcome of such an action.

Comment: Why should it interrupt the clean up routine? It's just another signal `INT` that the process recieves.

Comment: @chaos makes more sense now?

Comment: @chaos Why should it?  It should if the clean up routine has gotten hung up and you want to stop it.  Does it actually work this way?  Yes, quite often.  You can demonstrate it simply enough: make a bash script with the single line `trap "sleep 20 || echo clean up cancelled!"  EXIT ; sleep 10`.  Run the script and hit ctrl-C twice.  You will see that the second ctrl-C is passed to the "clean up" routine (in the trap statement) and terminates its `sleep` command.

Comment: @John1024 Ah, now I see it. Thanks for the script snippet^^ But, the cleanup is not cancelled see: `trap "sleep 20 || echo clean up cancelled!; sleep 10; echo 'but continued'" EXIT ; sleep 10` It's just the `sleep` commands that get the signals. We were both wrong xD

Comment: @chaos. Yes, OK.  The clean up wasn't cancelled but a command doing the 'clean up' was cancelled.

Comment: That's incorrect. Signal delivery is synchronous. If `isig` is on, as soon as CTRL-C is pressed and received by the kernel (for a terminal emulator, as soon as the terminal emulator writes it to the master side of the pseudo-terminal), the SIGINT signal is sent to all the processes in the foreground process group of the terminal. It may be blocked there, but it's not going to be delivered later to another process. Even if the terminal device buffer is full (the applications have not read any of the things you typed), the CTRL-C will jump the queue.

Comment: Yes, as an example, VLC interprets multiple Ctrl+C signals as a way to quit uncleanly, whereas a single Ctrl+C will attempt to quit cleanly.

Comment: @John1024 - congrats on 3k!

Answer (score 11):

You're wasting them. All that happens is that once the server finishes with the screen output, it will receive multiple <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>. The first one will be used to kill the process, and the following ones will end up in your shell, which will then look something like

```
[user@server]$ ^C
[user@server]$ ^C
[user@server]$ ^C
[user@server]$ ^C
[user@server]$ ^C
[user@server]$
```

Comment: The process doesn't necessarily exit when sending it a SIGINT. It could stay alive indefinitely and do something different every time Ctrl+C is pressed.

Comment: True. I was making assumptions about how the user is reading the file.

Answer (score 5):

**Short** answer: If the process reacts to it.

**Long** answer: When you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> the kernel sends a signal to the process. Which signal can be determined by the following command:

```
user@host:~# stty -a | grep -i "\^C"
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
```

See the man page of `stty`:

```
   intr CHAR
          CHAR will send an interrupt signal
```

It's the signal `INT`, also known as number 2. When the process has a signal handler it can react to this. Most processes do some cleanup jobs to end successfully.

Comment: Ctrl-Z usually sends SIGTSTP which can be handled (unlike SIGSTOP).

Comment: No, it's not the shell that sends the SIGINT to the process. It's the `kernel` (the line discipline of the terminal, the terminal driver) that sends SIGINT to every process in the foreground process _group_ of the terminal.

Comment: Future readers, also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120071/135943.

Answer (score 4):

You're right. The keypresses are being wasted. When you press <kbd>Crtl+C</kbd> and it gets detected, there are resources that need to be cleared, which is why it takes time. The one possible case I know where pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> is required, is when you want to cancel a Yum update process, where Yum requires you to press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> twice to confirm that you really want to cancel.

Answer (score 2):

Although only one <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> is necessary in the general case, there are some situations where it may be necessary. Python, for example, traps <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> when a new thread is being spawned, and so if something goes wrong in the midst of starting up many threads, it is necessary to resend it multiple times in order for it to get through to the `python` parent process without being caught.

Comment: This happens to me now and then when I create multi-threaded/processed python scripts. Sometimes several presses are needed before the main process is killed.

Answer (score 0):

I *always* have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> multiple times.  I have never had it respond on the first press, and have to use it multiple times until the system actually realizes there's a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> being sent.   Seems as though it actually misses/loses most of them.