# When does cat finish reading from a pipe?

Tags: pipe, c, cat, input

Given the following code, why does cat only print the contents of the pipe after I've typed `\n` or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>? What are the conditions for cat to actually print what it read?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
    int pid,p[2];
    char ch;
    pipe(p);
    if((pid=fork()) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error:can't create a child!\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    if(pid){
        close(p[0]);
        while((ch=getchar())!=EOF){
            write(p[1],&ch,1);
        }
        close(p[1]);
        wait(0);
    }else{
        close(p[1]);
        close(0);
        dup(p[0]);
        close(p[0]);
        execlp("cat","cat",NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you try running `cat` on its own on the command line, you'll see it doesn't print anything until you press Return or Ctrl+D. That's the expected behavior.

Comment: I think its due to:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: the returned value (which will only exist if execlp() fails ) needs to be passed to perror() and then call exit(-1)

Comment: For that matter, `while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF) { write(1,&ch,1); }` doesn't print anything until you press Return or Ctrl+D, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That has nothing to do with `cat`, pipes or buffering. Your "problem" is upstreams, at the terminal device.

If every character you enter at the keyboard in the terminal was available for reading by your application immediately and `cat`, then would you enter <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>, your application would read `a` then `^?` then `b` then `^M`, which is not what you want and is not  what you get.

What you want and get is for it to read `a^J` instead.

You get that because in the default *canonical* mode, the terminal device driver (the [tty line discipline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120071)) implements a *line editor* that lets you enter text and edit it (with limited capabilities), and the text you enter is only available for reading when you press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

To avoid that, you can tell the terminal device to leave that *canonical* mode. For instance, by doing `stty raw`, and you'll see your application and `cat` get the characters immediately, but probably the behaviour is not what you expect.

You'll also notice that for other types of input, like a pipe, characters are output as soon as they arrive as in :

```
(printf x; sleep 1; echo y) | that-command
```

Comment: Thank you and everyone else for answering. I was suspecting it wasn't related to anything that I knew, but had to ask somehow.

Answer (score -2):

follow this loop:

```
while((ch=getchar())!=EOF)
{
        write(p[1],&ch,1);
}
```

with:

```
char carriageReturn = 0x0D;
write( p[1], &carriageReturn, 1 );
```

Comment: Why? Can you explain the logic of your answer?