# How to prevent octal dump (od) returning?

Tags: command-line, io-redirection, serial-port, od

I am trying to read some output from `/dev/ttyUSB0`, using `od` on Ubuntu. So I used this command:

```
od -x --endian=big < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

When I used it yesterday it was not blocking and just showed stuff without escaping or returning like in this way:

```
0000000 55aa 03ff 0104 0616 835a a555 aaff 0302
0000020 1104 e0e1 025a a555 aa03 ff01 0506 8682 ...
```

But when I use it today `od` stops and returns right after printing:

```
0000000
```

May somebody know what I am missing here?

Comment: Perhaps your previous `od` command is still running and getting all the data.

Comment: What's the output of `stty -a < /dev/ttyUSB0`?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly that `tty` device is in canonical mode (the one where the tty line discipline implements a simple line editor) so an `eof` character (`^D` by default) received from the other end causes `read()` to return nothing.

That would be the same as when you run

```
od -vx --endian=big
```

in a terminal and type <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>.

Another explanation would be that the canonical mode is off but the `VMIN` termios setting is set to 0. With VMIN = 0, a `read()` on the device file returns whatever there is there ready to be read if any straight away and nothing otherwise (meaning end-of-file) (unless VTIME > 0 in which case it waits up to VTIME deciseconds for at least one byte).

Again, you can try it in a terminal with:

```
s=$(stty -g); stty -icanon min 0 time 0; od -vx --endian=big; stty "$s"
```

Check the current settings with:

```
stty -a < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

If that `/dev/ttyUSB0` is a serial device which is just meant to be used to transfer data and not to be used as a terminal, you should issue a

```
stty raw -echo < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

In effect, that disables most of the effects of the tty line discipline on it.

See [What are the responsibilities of each Pseudo-Terminal (PTY) component (software, master side, slave side)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117981) and your `termios(3)` and `stty(1)` man pages for more information.