# Does the process on the slave side of a pty talks to the line discipline or to the slave tty driver?

Tags: linux, pty

I have found two contradictory images of how a pseudo terminal (pty) works.

The first image shows that the process on the slave side of a pty talks to the line discipline:

[image]

The second image shows that the process on the slave side of a pty talks to the slave tty driver:

[image]

Which image is correct?

Comment: IMHO first digram seems wrong. Because the line terminal emulator suppose to be in between Hardware and process. in First image if you swap 'terminal line discipline' with 'pseudo terminal slave' it will be right.

Answer (score 5):

The second image is correct. (BTW, it comes [from here](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).)

From the accepted answer on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117981/what-are-the-responsibilities-of-each-pseudo-terminal-pty-component-software/):

> The line discipline is a software module (residing in the driver, in the kernel) pushed on top of a serial/pty device that sits between that device and the line/wire (the master side for a pty).
>
> (...)
>
> You can see the effect of disabling the tty line discipline by issuing stty raw -echo (note that the bash prompt or other interactive applications like vi set the terminal in the exact mode they need, so you want to use a dumb application like cat to experience with that). Then, everything that is written to the slave terminal device makes it immediately to the master side for xterm to read, and every character written by xterm to the master side is immediately available for reading from the slave device.

See also [this post](https://www.yabage.me/2016/07/08/tty-under-the-hood/) about ttys.

Comment: If the line discipline is _on top of_ the underlying device, then the _first_ image, which has exactly that, is the correct one.

Comment: It looks the third link changed to https://www.yabage.me/2016/07/08/tty-under-the-hood/