# How does the "speed" result returned by "stty -a" means?

Tags: linux, terminal

The `stty -a` command returned the following result:

[image]

What does "speed 38400 baud" means, does "baud" here have something to do with a serial port's baud rate?

Comment: It is not good to write questions in this way.  https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the baud rate of the tty.

Comment: For a tty to have a baud rate, this means that the tty have a "virtual serial port" (i.e. a serial port emulation, in the same way a physical tty have a physical serial port), since the baud rate is a property of a serial port, correct?

Comment: You already asked that as an actual question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401607/ .

Comment: @JdeBP But the answers I got on that question says that No, a tty does not have a "virtual serial port". And in this question I am finding out that a tty have a baud rate, and a baud rate is a property of a serial port!

Comment: No, you are finding out that a general answer to _a general question that does not mention virtual terminals_ is not the same as a detailed answer to a question that is _specifically about virtual terminals_.  This is in part because the general answer is not generally true, but also in part because you did not ask a good question and left out stuff from it that you are now bringing up in answer comments.