# Does ssh give access to the virtual console, to a terminal emulator, or what?

Tags: ssh, x11, clipboard, terminal-emulator, virtual-consoles

As far as I've understood, a terminal emulator is a GUI-based program which gives me a terminal-like viewport and allows me to interact with it just like I'd do with a terminal, except that it has all the support from the X system, so I suspect that `ssh user@ip` will not give me access to a terminal emulator running on the remote machine. If I want to use that, I need to connect to that machine via VNC, and then open a terminal emulator window in *that* desktop.

But do I get access to a virtual console (one that, physially on the remote machine I'd get via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*2*</kbd>, for instance)? I can `ssh -X ...`, which gives me access to the clipboard, which comes with X, so it kind of feels I'm not in a virtual console either...

---

As regards the proposed duplicate, since my question is specifically about SSH, the information I can gather is the following:

- > [Ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_shell) (which connects a terminal on one machine with programs on another machine)

  [from the accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/164309),
- > pseudoterminals [use PTY “devices” to arrange communication between console applications and the terminal-making program that runs in userspace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117981/what-are-the-responsibilities-of-each-pseudo-terminal-pty-component-software). Examples are X-based terminal emulators and sshd, that allocates a pseudotty for each login session.

  [from another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228052/164309),
- > There may be some application that "emulates" terminal accepting keystrokes from user and sending them somewhere (xterm and ssh are good examples). There is an API in Kernel called **pseudo terminal** for that. So your **tty** may really be connected to some application instead of real terminal. Xterm uses X11 to display text and ssh uses network connection for it.

  [from yet another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/376058/164309);

so the answer to my question seems to be "it gives access to a pseudo terminal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/153329

> pseudo-ttys, are provided (through a thin kernel layer) by programs called terminal emulators, such as Xterm (running in the X Window System), Screen (which provides a layer of isolation between a program and another terminal), Ssh(which connects a terminal on one machine with programs on another machine)

With ssh user@ip you get shell running in pseudo-terminal (not X11 terminal emulator).

With ssh -X you get X11 forwarding - an SSH protocol that enables users to run graphical applications on a remote server and interact with them using their local display and I/O devices.

X11 uses a client-server model, where an X Server is a program on a machine which manages access to graphical displays and input devices (monitors, mice, keyboards, etc.), and an X Client is a program which handles graphical data.

X Servers and X Clients can communicate over remote network.